# Resize UISwitch from XIB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uiswitch

I wonder is it really impossible to change default size of `UISwitch` directly from `XIB`? I am new in `iOS`, please tell me how do you resize.

Here is my login window, if would look better if I could resize the switch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I'm concerned.

Why do you want to do this anyways? I didn't try it in code but I think that you can't do this in code either.

The constant size of a `UISwitch` is there for a reason. Unlike other controls which have variable sizes, Apple obviously doesn't want you to change the size of a `UISwitch`.

You see, if you make the `UISwitch` wider, it doesn't look like a switch anymore. It looks more like a `UISlider`! If you make the `UISwitch` taller, the round thing that can move will become larger, right? And since the width doesn't change, the round thingy will have nowhere to move to! So it'll look bad either way. If you enlarge/diminish the switch while maintaining aspect ratio, The text beside it will have to be enlarged/diminished or it will look ugly. As a result, a lot more precious screen space is used (enlarge), or the switch is very hard to tap on (diminish).

So don't even try to do it.

Comment: Added a screenshot. Please see the switch could look better if I could minimise the size

Comment: You should do your login screen in a table view. `UISwitch` looks the best when put into a table cell. Try it! If you still want a resizable switch, try LLSwitch, it even has cool animations! https://github.com/lilei644/LLSwitch

Comment: If you think my answer or the other answer answers your question, please consider accepting either of those by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through code

```
switch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
```

Or else try UIButton with images of the your custom switch and change its selection property.

Answer (score 0):

You should not resize a UISwitch. It is indeed possible (by e.g. applying a `CGAffineTransform`), but as Apple states in their API guidelines, you shouldn't resize the default UI elements.

If you want a custom solution, you may create your own kind of switch - many apps use customized UI controls, and this is [not prohibited](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/switches/) by Apple. Create a subclass of `UIControl` or `UIButton` or whatever fits best for your needs, add custom initialization and state handling code and you're good to go! These controls can logically be resized as you want.